# Is it possible to tune the linear regression (hyper)parameter in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm starting to learn a bit of sci-kit learn and ML in general and i'm running into a problem.
I've created a model using linear regression.
the `.score` is good (above 0.8) but i want to get it better (perhaps to 0.9). 
I've searched the documentation of sklearn and googled this question but I cannot seem to find the answer.

My question is: **Is it possible to tune the** `LinearRegression` **model?** 
and if so, where can I find it?

```
#----- Forecast in hours -----#
forecast_out = 48


#----- Import and prep data -----#
using pandas to create X and y
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

#----- Linear Regression-----#
lr = LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None, normalize=False)

lr.fit(x_train, y_train)
lr_confidence = lr.score(x_test, y_test)
print("lr confidence: ", lr_confidence)
x_forecast = np.array(data.drop(['Prediction'],1))[-forecast_out:]
lr_prediction = lr.predict(x_forecast)
```

Comment: Provide a snippet of your code or give more details about your model, so that we can see where is room for improvement

Comment: added it to the question. I forgot to add it thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is always room for improvement. Parameters are there in the LinearRegression model. Use .get_params() to find out parameters names and their default values, and then use  .set_params(**params) to set values from a dictionary.
GridSearchCV and RandomSearchCV can help you tune them better than you can, and quicker.

This is a very open-ended question and you should just look up the documentation. It's all there, really, trust me - I've looked. Just Google LinearRegression documentation.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Comment: thanks. used .get_params(), i saw that i already specified the parameters in lr = LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None, normalize=False). feel kind of stupid right now :)

Comment: LinearRegression does not have many parameters, yes. I saw you've specified them already. There are many other ways to improve a model. Look into ensemble algorithms - BaggingRegressor or Stacking, Voting ensemble examples.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` does not have hyperparameters that can be tuned. So, instead please use `sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor`, which will provide many possiblites for tuning hyperparameters.
Its documentation can be found here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html .

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.
For Hyperparams tune Linear Regressions, try Lasso, Ridge or ElasticNet